# Stack Exchange Job Descriptions are not displayed properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, stackexchange.com

I was browsing the [we're hiring](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) link and looked at a few of the jobs posted. When I browse to any of the jobs that are posted on stackexchange.com URL the jobs are displayed screwy and the description is cut-off:

[Community Manager (bilingual English/Japanese)](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/community-manager-bilingual-english-japanese) looks like this:

[image]

There is no way that I can scroll down to read the rest of the job.  This is the same for the Sales Rep jobs ([London](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/sales-representative-account-executive-london), [New York](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/sales-representative-account-executive-new-york)) and the [recruiter jobs](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/recruiter-denver). These are all on the stackexchange.com url but the jobs on the careers.stackoverflow.com appear just fine.

I have cleared my cache and erased cookies.  I was able to reproduce this on both Firefox and Chrome for a Mac.

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195973/stack-exchange-job-descriptions-are-not-displayed-properly?noredirect=1#comment618280_195973) pointed out in the comments to look at the javascript console I am getting the following message in the Chrome console:

[image]

The text is:

> [blocked] The page at [https://hire.jobvite.com/CompanyJobs/Careers.aspx?nl=1&k=Job&j=oY9FXfwt&s=C…rs_Site&jvresize=https://stackexchange.com/Content/jobvite/FrameResize.html](https://hire.jobvite.com/CompanyJobs/Careers.aspx?nl=1&k=Job&j=oY9FXfwt&s=C%E2%80%A6rs_Site&jvresize=https://stackexchange.com/Content/jobvite/FrameResize.html) ran insecure content from https://stackexchange.com/Content/jobvite/FrameResize.html?height=1139.
> Careers.aspx?nl=1&k=Job&j=oY9FXfwt&s=Careers_Site&jvresize=https://stackexchange.com/Content/jobvite…:1

Comment: The page definitely loads slow, about 4-5 seconds before the main content shows up, but it is not cut off for me. I tested on Chrome 29.0.1547.65 and Safari 7.0 (9537.66) on Mac OS X 10.9 DP7.

Comment: I see the same cutoff at home (Chrome v?) and at work (IE8)

Comment: It looks fine in the latest versions of Chrome 29.0.1547.66, IE 10 and Firefox 23.0.1.

Comment: Slowness seems to be a result of loading jobvite content.  As for the cutoff, I haven't yet been able to reproduce the issue.  For someone who has the issue, is it consistent, or does it sometimes render correctly when you refresh?

Comment: @BenCollins At least for me, it is consistently cutoff.  I can't see the full description on any refresh.

Comment: @BenCollins something that may or may not be a clue, for me when the content does finally load, it seems to do it in two steps. In the first step, everything that bluefeet shows in her question is what's visible - I see the text cut off in exactly the same place hers does. Then the rest of that line and the rest of the page fill in about a tenth of a second later.

Comment: @BenCollins Another clue: the iframe that pulls in the jobvite content (yes, I said iframe, welcome back to 1998) is hard-coded to 500px, which happens to be exactly where bluefeet's text cuts off. It seems they start the iframe at 500px, then run some javascript to change the height of the iframe to fill the window. I bet if bluefeet runs a javascript console session she'll see some error happens either in that code or in some other place that affects that code or prevents it from running.

Comment: @BenCollins last comment, I promise: [I see this in my console](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eaEpG.png). Perhaps related.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yup, I have an error in my console. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I wonder if you click and hold inside the iframe content, and use your mouse wheel up or down, if it will scroll the inner contents?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It does not.

Comment: Where are you guys located?  I'm unable to repro from here either, I wonder if you're hitting another set of Jobvite servers that aren't handling https correctly.

Comment: @NickCraver I am an Phoenix.

Comment: @bluefeet: there's a [suggestion in a thread](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/OrwppKWbKnc/yg5xwYQpX00J) on Chrome's product forum that might help.  I'll try to investigate more tomorrow.

Comment: Can reproduce on Chrome 31.0.1622.7 Canary Aura, cannot reproduce on Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m (stable).

Comment: @BenCollins Like it says in that thread, if I click the shield in the address bar it will load the full page but that is the only way I can see the full description.

Comment: @bluefeet can you load https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/community-manager-bilingual-english-japanese and see the entire listing?  (note the _https_)

Comment: @BenCollins Yes, the full listing loads with that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was just a matter of having the URI protocol hardcoded to `https` when we shouldn't have.  The jobvite page loads some javascript from stackexchange.com which resizes the iframe to fit the listing (which probably accounts for that brief pause some of you noticed).  Loading and running unsecured JS on a secured site is a big no-no, so this breaks in several browser configurations.  I've switched these to be protocol-relative (i.e., `//hire.jobvite.com...` instead of `https://hire.jobvite.com...`), which should clear up the issue as soon as I build out.

In the meantime, a simple workaround is to browse https://stackexchange.com using SSL.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I initially thought it was my eyes playing tricks on me because this used to work.

Comment: Hey Ben this loads for the community manager job but it is not showing the full description on the other jobs posted using the stackexchange.com url (sales rep and recruiter)

Comment: @bluefeet: I found that after a regular refresh on each page it all works.  Not entirely sure why.

Comment: Unfortunately after more than a week later this is still happening, I can view the jobs if I click the shield in the address bar but it will not load fully without doing so.